# Is there a way to avoid sorting for a query with WHERE and ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by, where-in

I am looking to understand how a query with both `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` can be indexed properly. Say I have a query like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
ORDER BY date_created
LIMIT 3
```

With an index on `date_created`, it seems like the execution plan will prefer to use the `PRIMARY` key and then sort the results itself. This seems to be very slow when it needs to sort a large amount of results.

I was reading through [this guide](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by) on indexing for ordered queries which mentions an almost identical example and it mentions:

> If the database uses a sort operation even though you expected a pipelined execution, it can have two reasons: (1) the execution plan with the explicit sort operation has a better cost value; **(2) the index order in the scanned index range does not correspond to the order by clause.**

This makes sense to me but I am unsure of a solution. Is there a way to index my particular query and avoid an explicit sort or should I rethink how I am approaching my query?

Comment: It seems strange that you are filtering on `id`.  Is the `id` not unique in the table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff id is unique, the scenario is I have a list of ids from outside of this database and i'd like to select the first N records ordered by a date column.

Answer (score 1):

The Optimizer is caught between a rock and a hard place.

Plan A:  Use an index starting with `id`; collect however many rows that is; sort them; then deliver only 3.  The downside:  If the list is large and the ids are scattered, it could take a long time to find all the candidates.

Plan B:  Use an index starting with `date_created` filtering on `id` until it gets 3 items.  The downside:  What if it has to scan all the rows before it finds 3.

If you know that the query will always work better with one query plan than the other, you can use an "index hint".  But, when you get it wrong, it will be a slow query.

A partial answer...  If `*` contains bulky columns, both approaches *may* be hauling around stuff that will eventually be tossed.  So, let's minimize that:

```
SELECT u.*
    FROM ( SELECT id
            FROM users
            WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
            ORDER BY date_created
            LIMIT 3           -- not repeated
         ) AS x
    JOIN users AS u  USING(id)
    ORDER BY date_created;    -- repeated
```

Together with

```
INDEX(date_created, id),
INDEX(id, date_created)
```

Hopefully, the Optimizer will pick one of those "covering" indexes to perform the "derived table" (subquery).  If so that will be somewhat efficiently performed.  Then the `JOIN` will look up the rest of the columns for the 3 desired rows.

If you want to discuss further, please provide

- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- How many ids you are likely to have.
- Why you are not already `JOINing` to another table to get the ids.
- Approximately how many rows in the table.

Comment: Could you expand on joining to another table? I was under the impression the problem would remain since it would need to follow either plan A or plan B mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @CaTs - True.  It is still stuck making the right or wrong decision of which way to perform the subquery.  But it should use one of my indexes; scanning an index is usually faster because of being smaller.

Comment: @CaTs - True, but at least it avoids the back and forth to get the list of ids.  And, in some situations, it may provide the Optimizer with other ways to perform the query.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet might to to write this in a more complicated way:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM ((SELECT u.*
       FROM users u
       WHERE id = 1
       ORDER BY date_created
       LIMIT 3
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT u.*
       FROM users u
       WHERE id = 2
       ORDER BY date_created
       LIMIT 3
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT u.*
       FROM users u
       WHERE id = 3
       ORDER BY date_created
       LIMIT 3
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT u.*
       FROM users u
       WHERE id = 4
       ORDER BY date_created
       LIMIT 3
      ) 
     ) u
ORDER BY date_created
LIMIT 3;
```

Each of the subqueries will now use an index on `users(id, date_created)`.  The outer query is then sorting at most 12 rows, which should be trivial from a performance perspective.

Comment: This does not seem like it would scale well which is where my issue lies.

Comment: @CaTs . . . Of course this would scale well -- very well.  That is why I provided the answer.  Indexes can be used for the subqueries.  Sorting a handful of rows is trivial.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a composite index on `(id, date_created)` - that will give the engine the option of using an index for both steps - but the optimiser may still choose not to.

If there aren't many rows in your table or it thinks the resultset will be small it's quicker to sort after the fact than it is to traverse the index tree.

If you really think you know better than the optimiser (which you don't), you can use index hints to tell it what to do, but this is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: In the article I linked, it mentions that a composite index likely won't work for this scenario since values for id or date_created will be out of order after sorted by the other field. I tried a composite index and found it was ignored.